# File cant be found third party dll in console app

Tags: c#, .net, windows, console-application

I built a console application and "built" the solution, taking over the API to a server to run as a scheduled task. The console app uses a 3rd party app, but when the tool runs on the server, I get an error saying the .dll can't be found. What is the proper way to deploy this?

Thanks

Comment: How did you install the 3-rd party app on your development computer? Does the missing DLL belong to your app or to the 3-rd party app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the References folder in your project, highlight the third-party .dll and right click, in the Properties you should find the setting for 'Copy Local' and set it to True. When you do a Build take the contents of the Debug or Release folder and deploy it on your server. You can also 'Publish' but this usually makes an installer which I don't usually need.

If you continue to get errors make sure the dependent.dlls to your third party .dll are also in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to specify a run directory with the schedulded task or you need to deploy it to the Global Assembly Cache. 
Global Assembly Cache will only work when the dll/assembly is strongly named and signed, but this would be the better way.